# Importance sampling over discrete probability distribution

Tags: statistics, random-walk, random, sampling

Suppose that I know the stationary distribution of samplings via random walks and I want to calculate some expectation values. The stationary distribution is a discrete probability distribution. It is very costly to sample data from the stationary distribution to compute the expectations. So my question is that can I use importance sampling to compute the expectations with possible lower number of samples needed and lower variance?

From my knowledge, importance sampling can be used for continuous probability distribution. Can it be applied to discrete one?

If so, is there any available example for the discrete case?

If not, is there any sampling technique I can use to efficiently compute the expectation?

I attempted using importance sampling which requires the user to give a proposal distribution. But I find difficulties defining a discrete proposal probability distribution. Is there any guidance to achieve that for discrete case?

Comment: Do you have a PMF available (i.e. a black box function that can compute P(X=x) without being prohibitively slow)? If so, about how many values of x are in there? If it is less than about 100 billion, then it should be no big deal to use binary search on a CDF table. If space is a problem, you could use a partial CDF table, which can be used to accelerate evaluation of the CDF without actually storing all of its values. Even just storing 1% of the table can greatly improve evaluation time.

Comment: (Cont.) That said, if you have the PMF, you can do better than this binary search method. One such optimization is called the alias method. This goes through a preprocessing step, where you divide up the $n$ random values up into $n$ bins, each containing 2 possible values (sometimes the same one twice, other times 2 different ones). Each value in each bin has an associated probability, with the total probability in each bin being $1/n$. Thus when you are done you can pick a random bin, and then sample a Bernoulli random variable to pick an element of the bin.

Comment: Whether you use an optimization like this or not, you can indeed importance sample provided you have the PMF. It works the same way as the continuous case: $\sum_n f(n) p(n) = \sum_n \frac{f(n) p(n)}{q(n)} q(n)$, so $E_p[f]=E_q[fp/q]$. You choose $q$ so that $fp/q$ varies as little as possible.

Comment: If you don't have the PMF then you should be using some dynamical Monte Carlo method rather than thinking of this in the same framework as traditionally computing an expected value by direct sampling. In this setting the analogue of "importance sampling" appears in methods like Metropolis-Hastings, where choosing a good prior jump distribution reduces the frequency of move rejection, which accelerates convergence.

Comment: @lan: Thank you very much for your reply. In my case, I know the PMF (i.e., the stationary distribution). The number of values of x is very huge where each x is a connected subgraph of some given size k. Thus, the number of values of x equals to the number of subgraphs of size k in the original graph.

Comment: What order of magnitude is that in your actual situation though?

Comment: @lan: (Cont.) One of one major problem in my question is that: given a subgraph x, I can compute P(X=x) with some proved theories, but I do not have knowledge of how many x are there. Thus, I need to collect x on-the-fly by running random walks on the whole graph. So to compute some expectation E(f(x)), the number of random walks needed is very large. I think that, to use any advanced techniques, I need to have prior knowledge the size of sample spaces and each sample x. In my problem, I do not have this knowledge.

Comment: @lan: So simply speaking, I am computing some expectation E(f(x)) and collecting the knowledge of sample space of x at the same time. It is not realistic to get prior knowledge of all subgraphs of size k.

Comment: OK, well, that's really rather problematic in terms of doing methods like I suggested. You can try to do a method where you modify $f$ and the walk itself, so that the walk spends more time where $f$ is large.

Comment: @lan: that is a good suggestion. Thank you.